# Rearranging the shape of multiple matrices in R

Tags: r, csv, dataset, social-networking, import-from-csv

This is a double barrelled **R** question.  I have a folder of data sets (in .csv) and they need to be altered before analysis.  Each data set is a 1X10 matrix like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

and need to turn it into into the following 5X5 matrix inserting 1s on the diagonal:

```
1
1 1 
2 3 1
4 5 6 1
7 8 9 10 1
```

How can accomplish this transformation on multiple files in a folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
dir.in  <- "aaa"  # replace with your own input dir
dir.out <- "bbb"  # replace with your own output dir

files.in  <- list.files(dir.in, full.names = TRUE)
files.out <- file.path(dir.out, basename(files.in))

data.in <- lapply(files.in, scan, sep = ",")

mat.out <- lapply(data.in, function(x){ M <- diag(1, 5)
                                        M[upper.tri(M)] <- x
                                        t(M) })

mapply(write.csv, mat.out, files.out, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I tried it and got the following error:                             > data.in <- lapply(files.in, scan, sep = ",")
Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "r") : cannot open file 'sn1.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: Try with `full.names = TRUE`. Edited.